# Code not returning expected number of even and odds

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a function that takes in a list of numbers and will return how many even numbers and odd numbers there are in the list. However, I passed in a list of numbers but I'm getting 0 results.

Here is my function -

```
 public static string HowManyEvenAndOdds(List<int> numbers)
  {
     int numOfOdds = 0;
     int numOfEvens = 0;
     int numOfBoth = 0;

     foreach (int i in numbers) {
        bool isEven = i % 2 == 0;
        bool isOdd = i % 3 == 0;

        numOfBoth = isEven && isOdd ? numOfBoth++ : numOfBoth;
        numOfEvens = isEven ? numOfEvens++ : numOfEvens;
        numOfOdds = isOdd ? numOfOdds++ : numOfOdds;
     }

     return string.Format("This list has {0} odd numbers,\n{1} even numbers,\nand {2} numbers that are even and odd.", numOfOdds, numOfEvens, numOfBoth);

  }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? I debugged through it but none of the lists are incrementing.

Thanks

Comment: An [odd number](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_number) is defined as "a number that is not a multiple of 2". `i % 3 == 0` is **not** how you test for odd numbers. And no number can be both even and odd.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment... surely `numOfBoth` should either just be the total numbers passed through, e.g. `numOfBoth = numOfEvens + numOfOdds` or, I'm not sure what else it would be

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think I overthought that.

Comment: @Josh I had a misunderstanding. I thought number's that can be divided into 2 and 3 would be considered both. Was a little confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Schachaf Gortler's answer as well as p.s.w.g's comment. Just do:

```
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    // A number is even if, and only if, it's evenly divisible by 2
    if (number % 2 == 0)
       numEvens++;
    // A number is odd if, and only if, it's NOT evenly divisible by 2
    // Alternatively, a number is odd if it isn't even and vice versa
    else
       numOdds++;
}
```

As p.s.w.g. mentioned, there's no such thing as a number that's both even and odd, so eliminate that completely.

Incidentally, numOfEvens++ retrieves the value *and then* increments it, which is why your code didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to cite other answers and comments in _your_ answer, just the code will do.

Comment: This worked! But I'm confused why my expression wasn't running. When I wrote numOfEvens = isEven ? numOfEvens++ : numOfEvens;

It kept numOfEvens as 0.

Answer (score 6):

your are not calculating odd in the correct way
 i%3 does not catch 5 which is also an odd number, try this instead

```
 bool isEven = i % 2 == 0;
 bool isOdd =!isEven;
```

Comment: True - the test for odd numbers also misses a *lot* of other odd numbers, such as 1, 7, 11, 13, and 17. In fact, it misses *every* prime number by definition, plus plenty of non-prime numbers like 5 and 25.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at your test for isOdd

Answer (score 1):

Use the Linq [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) extension.

```
int numOfOdds = numbers.Count(x => x % 2 != 0);
int numOfEvens = numbers.Count(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

Of course you don't need to evaluate both expressions, as per the comment below.

Comment: No need to enumerate the list twice. `numOfEvents = numbers.Count - numOfOdds;`

Comment: Sure, I meant to simply show both of them as independent. I agree with you: we don't need both together